# Bounded version of linear and quadratic Hasse--Minkowski theorem

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, lattices, quadratic-forms, discrepancy-theory

The Hasse-Minkowski theorem states that if

$$Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij} x_ix_j$$
is a quadratic form with $a_{ij} \in \mathbb Z$ and $\det (a_{ij}) \neq 0$, then the equation
$$Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$$
has a nontrivial solution in the integers if and only if it has a solution in the reals and all the $p$-adics.

> 1. Can there be a bounded version to this statement such as  if
>      $$Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij} x_ix_j$$
>      is a quadratic form with $a_{ij} \in \mathbb Z$ and $\det (a_{ij}) \neq 0$, then the equation
>      $$Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$$
>      has a nontrivial solution in the integers with each coordinate bound in absolute value by $B$ iff $\dots$?
> 2. Can there be a bounded version to at least a linear version of the statement such as if
>      $$L(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{i} x_i$$
>      is a linear form with $a_{i} \in \mathbb Z$ and **some criteria**, then the equation
>      $$L(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$$
>      has a nontrivial solution in the integers with each coordinate bound in absolute value by $B$ iff $\dots$?

Comment: Possibly you can get some local criterion using weak approximation, but its not clear to me exactly how this would go.

Answer (score 2):

The linear case is Siegel's lemma. I do not know the quadratic case: Cassels does not have it, perhaps O'Meara does. Note that the regulator is closely related where we seek a representation of $1$ by $x^2-dy^2$ in integers, and bounds on the regulator are hard.

Comment: in case of interest: this user asked a fairly specific question a month ago, and I recently found out how to do it, here is the final of my several answers there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392683/on-largest-box-not-containing-integer-vector-solutions/2435494#2435494

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, the answer is yes; you can find the statement and a proof in Cassels (pp 86-89).  A far reaching generalization was obtained by J. Vaaler in 1987 concerning the height of a totally isotropic subspace of quadratic forms on subspace of $F^n$, where $F$ is a number field.  Since then there have been various types of results like that.  You may want to check out Lenny Fukshansky's papers.  A recent paper of him with Chan and Henshaw generalizes Vaaler's result to zeros avoiding algebraic varieties.