# Necessary and Sufficient condition for Sharpness of Bombieri and Vaaler's result on Siegel's lemma?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, geometry-of-numbers, diophantine-geometry

This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_lemma) currently quotes Bombieri and Vaaler's [result](https://eudml.org/doc/143033) on Siegel's lemma:

Suppose we are given a system of $m$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns such that $n>m$, say

$a_{11}x_1+\dots+a_{1n}x_n=0$

$\dots$

$a_{m1}x_1+\dots+a_{mn}x_n=0$

where the coefficients are rational integers, not all $0$, and bounded by $B$. The system then has a solution

$(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$

with the $x$s all rational integers, not all $0$, and bounded by

$(nB)^{m/(n-m)}.$

Bombieri and Vaaler ($1983$) gave the following sharper bound for the $x$'s:

$\max|x_j|\leq\Big(D^{-1}\sqrt{\mathsf{det}(AA^T)}\Big)^{1/(n-m)}$

where $D$ is the greatest common divisor of the $m$ by $m$ minors of the matrix $A$, and $A^T$ is its transpose.

I want to know under what conditions on $A$ we can guarantee an '$\alpha$ - factor gap'. Denote $\Lambda$ to be set of solution vectors $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\Bbb Z^n$ for the system ($\Lambda$ is the kernel lattice).

Given $\alpha\in(0,1)$, '$\alpha$ - factor gap' guarantee basically means the inequality
$$\alpha\Big(D^{-1}\sqrt{\mathsf{det}(AA^T)}\Big)^{1/(n-m)}\leq\min_{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\Lambda}\max|x_j|\leq\Big(D^{-1}\sqrt{\mathsf{det}(AA^T)}\Big)^{1/(n-m)}$$ is satisfied.

Let $\bf{x}_1,\bf{x}_2,\dots,\bf{x}_{n-m}\in\Bbb Z^n$ be full basis (each $\bf{x}_i\in\Bbb Z^n$) for solutions to the system (which is $\Lambda$). That is for every $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\Lambda$ there exists $r_1,\dots,r_{n-m}\in\Bbb Z$ such that $$(x_1,\dots,x_n)=r_1\bf{x}_1+\dots+r_{n-m}\bf{x}_{n-m}$$ holds.

At every $i\in\{1,\dots,n-m\}$ let $\lambda_{i,\infty}(\Lambda)$ be the $i$th successive minimum of kernel lattice in the $L^\infty$ norm.

> > 1. To guarantee an '$\alpha$ - factor gap's is it sufficient to show there is a $T\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\alpha^{n-m}T\leq \prod_{i=1}^{n-m}\lambda_{i,\infty}(\Lambda)\leq T$$ holds where $T$ is some suitable integer in $[0,(n-m)^{\frac{n-m}2}\mathsf{det}(\Lambda)]$?
> > 2. What is a sufficient condition if 1. does not work out?

Please also refer [Bounded version of linear and quadratic Hasse--Minkowski theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280031/bounded-version-of-linear-)‌​and-quadratic-hasse-‌​minkowski-theorem.

Comment: why negvote????

Comment: Bombieri and Vaaler prove a more precise result giving a full basis $\mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_{N-M}$ of solutions such that the geometric mean $(\prod_{i=1}^{N-M} \max_j{|x_{ij}|})^{1/(N-M)}$ fulfills the same upper bound. For a fixed $\alpha \in (0,1)$, this implies in your question that your desired lower bound may not hold unless the discrete abelian group of integer solutions of $A.\mathbf{x} = 0$ has a basis of elements of nearly constant $L^{\infty}$-norm. This is an extremely stringent condition that 'holds with probability $0$' in any reasonable probabilistic sense.

Comment: You may also be interested in Vaaler's paper *The best constant in Siegel's lemma* (Monats. Math., 2003), which determines the sharpest possible form of the $L^2$ variant of Siegel's lemma, where your $\max(|X_j|)$ is replaced by the $L^2$-norm $\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^N |X_j|^2 }$.

Comment: [My first comment above should read "$\ldots$ unless [it] has nearly equal successive minima for the $L^{\infty}$ norm." Not that it merely has a basis of about the same norm -  sorry about this. If you now think of $A$ by duality as the $\mathbb{Z}$-module of integer solutions of $A.\mathbf{x}  = 0$, and think of this as a random submodule of $\mathbb{Z}^N$ of rank $N-M$, you see how exceedingly rare is you requirement of a commensurable lower bound on the size of a non-zero solution. ]

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov you state 'unless [it] has nearly equal successive minima for the $L^∞$ norm' we cannot guarantee closeness to BV bound. So it looks like it is necessary. Is this also sufficient? Could you post a full answer? It will be very helpful to me.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Is there a proof that nearly equal successive minima for $L^\infty$ norm implies upper bound is tight?

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Why should the successive min criteria even be necessary? BV only prove basis where upper bound and geometric mean of quantity you quote agree. That does not preclude much shorter integer vectors in the subspace. On other hand there may be constructions where lower bound and upper bound agree.

Comment: @Turbo: See the display defining "$\alpha$-factor gap." If $0 < \lambda_1 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_k$ have a geometric mean bounded by a quantity $M$, then you cannot have them all $\geq \alpha M$ unless $\lambda_1 \geq \alpha \lambda_k$, right?

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Unclear. If $\lambda_{gm}^k=\lambda_1\cdot\dots\cdot\lambda_k\geq \alpha M\cdot\dots\cdot\alpha M=\alpha^kM^k$ then $\lambda_{gm}\geq \alpha M$ holds. Let $\lambda_{gm}\leq M$ hold. Then $\alpha M\leq\lambda_{gm}\leq M$ holds. Why is $\lambda_1\geq \alpha\lambda_k$ necessary? Let $\lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_{k-1}=\alpha M<\lambda_k=M+1$ and so $\lambda_1=\alpha M< \alpha\lambda_k$. Then $\lambda_{gm}=(\lambda_1\cdot\dots\cdot\lambda_k)^{1/k}=(\alpha M)^{(k-1)/k}(M+1)^{1/k}=\alpha^{(k-1)/k} M(1+\frac1M)^{1/k}$.......

Comment: .......and $\big(1+1/M\big)>1>\alpha\implies \lambda_{gm}\geq\alpha M$ and $\alpha^{(k-1)/k}(1+\frac1M)^{1/k}<1$ or equivalently $\alpha^{k-1}<\frac M{M+1}\implies\lambda_{gm}<M$ still holds.

Comment: @Turbo: It is a long question and I have to run in a moment, but I'll try to have a look later in the day.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov actually the question is short. Everything below 'here is the heuristic' is not part of question.

Comment: @Turbo: Hang on, in my comment above I should be saying $\lambda_1 \geq \alpha^k \lambda_k$ (not $\alpha \lambda_k$). This is since $ \lambda_k = M^k / (\lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_{k-1}) \leq M^k / \lambda_1^{k-1} \leq M \alpha^{1-k} \leq \lambda_1 \alpha^{-k}$. This is what I intended with successive minima. It is still an exceedingly rare condition.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov However not as rare as originally thought.

Comment: This is actually what I initially thought when I commented at the time: it is a condition that holds with zero probability in any meaningful sense of that word. I don't think it holds in your new example, but I would need to look closer into it to be sure.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov By high probability I mean at least probability $>1/n^\epsilon$ at any fixed $\epsilon>0$ (that is for every $\epsilon>0$ we can find a large $n$ such that it holds with probability $>1/n^\epsilon$).